# How to process this data to create a stacked bar chart?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

so I am writing a program that monitors and records your usage time of foreground applications and saves them in a SQL database. I then want to retrieve the data from previous days and compile it all together into a stacked bar chart. Here, the x-axis will have the different days over which usage was recorded, and the various stacks in each bar will represent each app that was used.

In my program, I created 2 tables, one to record each day's app usage (with each new day's data having a different primary key id), and another table to record the primary key for each day.

Table 1:

| _id | Application | usage_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Google Chrome | 245.283942928347 |
| 1 | PyCharm | 450.3939754962921 |
| 1 | SQLiteStudio | 140.2376308441162 |
| 1 | Google Chrome | 5.008131980896 |

Table 2:

| Date | daily_id |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-07-18 07:25:25.376734 | 0 |
| 2021-07-18 07:27:57.419574 | 1 |

Within my stacked bar chart program, I have come up with this code to refine the data to put into the stacked bar chart:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('daily_usage_monitor.sqlite', detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES)

all_app_data = conn.execute('SELECT all_usage_information.date, monitor.application, monitor.usage_time FROM all_usage_information INNER JOIN monitor ON all_usage_information.daily_id = monitor._id ORDER BY all_usage_information.date, monitor.usage_time ASC').fetchall()

for date, app, usage_time in all_app_data:
    print(f'{date} - {app}: {usage_time}')
conn.close()

daily_data = {}

# Create nested dictionary - key = each date, value = dictionary of different apps & their time usage durations
for date, app, time in all_app_data:
    conditions = [date not in daily_data, app != 'loginwindow']
    if all(conditions):
        daily_data[date] = {app: time}
    elif not conditions[0] and conditions[1]:
        daily_data[date].update({app: time})

print(daily_data)   # TODO: REMOVE AFTER TESTING

total_time = 0
# Club any applications that account for <5% of total time into 1 category called 'Other'
for date, app_usages in daily_data.items():
    total_time = sum(time for app, time in app_usages.items())

    refined_data = {}
    for key, value in app_usages.items():
        if value/total_time < 0.05:
            refined_data['Others'] = refined_data.setdefault('Others', 0) + value
        else:
            refined_data[key] = value
    daily_data[date] = refined_data

print(daily_data)   # TODO: REMOVE AFTER TESTING

# Takes the nested dictionary and breaks it into a labels list and a dictionary with apps & time usages for each day
# Sorts data so it can be used to create composite bar chart
final_data = {}
labels = []
for date, app_usages in daily_data.items():
    labels.append(date)
    for app, time in app_usages.items():
        if app not in final_data:
            final_data[app] = [time]
        else:
            final_data[app].append(time)
```

This is the kind of output I am currently getting:
{'Google Chrome': [245.283942928347, 190.20031905174255], 'SQLiteStudio': [145.24058270454407], 'PyCharm': [1166.0021023750305]}

The problem here is that for the days where an application had 0 usage time, it is not being recorded in the list. Therefore, the insertion order of the stacked bar chart will not be correct and will show the wrong apps for the wrong dates. How can I fix this?

This is one method I tried, but of course it's not working because you cannot index into a dictionary:

```
for app, usage in final_data.items():
    for date, app_usages in daily_data.items():
        if app not in app_usages:
            usage.insert(app_usages.index(app), 0)
```

Comment: Seems like you need to get a distinct of Application      from Table1 and initialize `daily_data` with all possible applications ever done = 0 to start with ...

Comment: I had considered that but it wouldn't be very effective considering that there are many additional applications that the user may have that I am not able to cover in my initialization. Is there any other way you can think of?